# Poor review audit question

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

This review item in the close votes queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11509053?filter-closereason=offtopic appears to belong on Super User as it is about the use of SSH on a command line and asks for the meaning of an error message.

There is no programming aspect to it; the most up-voted answer indicates that it is a simple software version problem (which would be a configuration problem).

The "STOP! Look and listen" claims "There are no major problems with this question."

From the [on-topic subjects](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

- a specific programming problem

No.

- a software algorithm

No.

- software tools commonly used by programmers

I was not aware that command line SSH questions were on topic on SO. The tag for [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh) states "Common authentication and configuration problems are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

No, not unique to software development.

I cannot in good conscience click "I understand" in the review audit for this one.

Please can someone let me know what I have missed that makes the question on-topic for SO, or remove it from the audit questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> as it is about the use of SSH on a command line

No, it's not. It's about using an SSH library from code. That's very much appropriate on SO. This looks like a good audit to me.

> There is no programming aspect to it; the most up-voted answer indicates that it is a simple software version problem (which would be a configuration problem).

Yes, it sometimes turns out that a problem while programming gets solved by something other than programming. There's no programming aspect in the answer. There is a programming aspect in the question, and that's what should determine whether the question is appropriate.

Comment: It turns out that as I know nothing about Laravel and that it has its own CLI, "Artisan", I should have clicked "Skip". Thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: That, of course, isn't relevant here. The question would be just as valid if Artisan didn't exist.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I can sympathize with you here. I don't know anything about these technologies, and at first glance, that might look like an off-topic question to me, too. Fortunately, [there is no shame in using skip](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip). That is definitely what you should do in cases like this.